# How to get data from single table with two forigin keys from that table in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5

It's may be my question not clear to you but my English is weak. so suppose, I have two tables 'user' and 'project'. this project table contain two foreign keys from user table.

That's because, I want to indicate two people

```
(1) person who implement the project (Employee)
(2) person who Mange or supervise the project (Manager)
```

```
user                       project 
--------------------       -----------------------------------------
user_id | name     |       |p_id  | name | manager_id | employee_id |
--------------------       -----------------------------------------
001     | manager  |       p001   |ABC   | 001       | 002
002     | employee |
```

you can see, project table refer user id as foreign key (manager_id and employee_id). because those two persons are users initially.

My question is, How can i get these users same time separately  **by using php laravel (Laravel Framework 5.5.45)**  when i am gonna show project details such as below?

```
Project
-------------------------
project Name : ABC
Manage By : manager
Conduct By : employee
-------------------------
```

I have found MySQL query but i haven't it right now to post here. i forgot to bookmark that stack overflow link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use eloquent relationship for this. Use two relation in your Project Model like below:

```
class Project extends Model
{
    public function manager()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'manager_id');
    }

    public function employee()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'employee_id');
    }
}
```

So in view it will be something like

```
Project Name : {{ $project->name }}
Managed By : {{ $project->manager->name }}
Conduct By : {{ $project->employee->name }}
```

Check out Laravel Eloquent Relationship [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Actually i didn't user 'id' term end of the foreign key. Ex (employee). will it be a problem? because , neither 2 solutions work for me.

Comment: what do you mean by didn't user id? i can see you have `manager_id` and `employee_id` on your project table.

Comment: yes i am sorry.. i mentioned it. but, i didn't add foreign key as employee_id by mistake.( employee ) so will it change the outcome ?

Comment: then in relation use just `employee` instead of `employee_id` as foreign key.

Comment: you won't get anything using `{{ $project->employee->name }}`?? it must give you the employee name or error if everything is set correctly.

Comment: yes! i was also wonder, i checked by using postman request. so nothing, same old foreign key appeared!

Comment: does `{{ $project->employee->name }}` print foreign key only but not the name in view?

Comment: no, get the output to postman. It shows the out put json or whatever. so only foreign key that i have specified in there.

Comment: obviously it will show the foreign key in postman response because in your db you have the foreign key.

Comment: omg.. i am using laravel as api. so what should i do now? i didn't mentioned it because i thought it's not important. i thought both api and other way working as the same way!!!

Comment: well now it depends how you are returning the response. if you are using laravel api resource you can set the value in the response.

Answer (score 1):

You should add

> protected $table = 'project' because your table name like single. Laravel requred a single "s" whenever you create table like users,projects,services. in pivot table table name like user_role , role_permission etc.

```
class Project extends Model{

  protected $table = 'project';

  public function manager() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'manager_id');
  }

  public function employee(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'employee_id');
  }
}
```

For Show at Blade file.

```
// Controller 
public function index(){
  $projects = Project::all();
  return view('blade_File_Destination_Here',compact('projects'));
}
```

## View Process at Blade File

```
@foreach($projects as $project)
   Project
   -------------------------
   Project Name : {{ $project->name }}
   Manage By : {{ $project->manager->name }}
   Conduct By : {{ $project->employee->name }}
   -------------------------

@endforeach
```

## Hope so it will be work for you

## Thank you

Comment: Actually i didn't user 'id' term end of the foreign key. Ex (employee). will it be a problem? because , neither 2 solutions work for me.

Comment: When you use laravel model eloquent , Table name must be plural for single table name. Single table name means here , Model Name : Employee , Employee table name must be like this 'employees' . Either you have to define your table name at model . Guess your table name is 'employee' you have to put protected $table ='YourTableName'; at Model. Either won't work properly through eloquent query